# Sending Multiline Body using HTTP post request in ruby is not working

Tags: ruby, http

**TL;DR:** I have to make an HTTP post request, which is working using CURL but not in ruby.

If I use CURL from terminal(Using Ubuntu)

```
curl https://api.kite.trade/session/token  \
   -H "X-Kite-Version: 3" \
   -d "api_key=XXX" \
   -d "request_token=XXX" \
   -d "checksum=XXX"
```

The above CURL request works and I am able to get the response. However if I try to use HTTP gem in ruby, it doesn't work.

```
response = http.headers("X-Kite-Version"=>"3").post(
      "https://api.kite.trade/session/token",
      body: ("api_key=" + @api_key +"\n\r" "request_token=" + @request_token +"\n\r" "checksum=" + checksum_hash.to_s)
    )
```

I tried different combinations of using `"\n"`,`"\n\r"`.
I tried putting .html_safe after `"("api_key=" + @api_key +"\n\r" "request_token=" + @request_token +"\n\r" "checksum=" + checksum_hash.to_s)"`

I tried the below method:

```
params = [["api_key","XXX"],["request_token","XXX"],["checksum","XXX"]]
```

tried to URI encode the above params and pass into the "body" parameter of http request. However it didn't work.

In most of these scenarios when I try calling using the HTTP gem, I get the below error message -

> {"status":"error","message":"`api_key` should be minimum 6 characters in length.","data":null,"error_type":"InputException"}

Most probably the data is not getting passed in a way, the server API would understand. Also I don't have any control on the server API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL's `-d` option sends the specified data in a POST request to the server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form.

This translates to `set_form_data` in Ruby, like this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("https://api.kite.trade/session/token")

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request["X-Kite-Version"] = "3"
request.set_form_data(
  "api_key" => "XXX",
  "checksum" => "XXX",
  "request_token" => "XXX",
)

req_options = { use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https" }

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

# response.code
# response.body
```

Comment: This is using the net/http package. I was able to use this package to do the same. However I wanted to know, why the HTTP package was not working, because essentially, they are going to generate the same HTTP message. I am still marking the answer correct, because I already tried this and I know it works

Comment: Using the `http` gem likely failed for the same reason, because you passed the data in the `body` instead of as [`form` data](https://github.com/httprb/http/wiki/Passing-Parameters#form-data).